# Storing data from 1 table to another tables in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am pretty new to **Laravel**. I have a **Table** named Leads and **Three** other tables named **Contacts**, **Companies**, and **Opportunities**. 
What I am trying to do is extract the data from the Leads table to these 3 other tables. Something like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWYVX.jpg . The way I want to achieve this is kind of like this: When the user clicked the 'Convert Lead' button, a modal will appear like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0dxF.jpg and if the user ticked the checkbox button for the Convert to Opportunity, an extra field will appear for the user to fill in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWYSF.jpg

> I have made the necessary files for the process (maybe)

LeadController:

```
    {
        return view('leads.create')
            ->withUsers($this->users->getAllUsersWithDepartments())
            ->withClients($this->clients->listAllClients())
            ->withIndustries($this->clients->listAllIndustries())
            ->withLeadSource($this->leads->listAllSources());
    }
public function convertLeads($id)
    {
        $lead = Lead::findOrFail($id);

        $company = new Companies;
        $opportunity = new Opportunity;
        $contact = new Contact;

        $company->lead_id = $lead->id;
        $company->name = $lead->company_name;
        $company->phone = $lead->company_phone;
        $company->email = $lead->company_mail;
        $company->address1 = $lead->company_address1;
        $company->address2 = $lead->company_address2;
        $company->state = $lead->company_state;
        $company->zipcode = $lead->company_zipcode;
        $company->city = $lead->company_city;
        $company->country = $lead->company_country;

        $company->save();

        $contact->name = $lead->lead_name;
        $contact->job_title = $lead->position;
        $contact->email = $lead->mail;
        $contact->primary_number = $lead->lead_phone;
        $contact->description = $lead->description;
        $contact->client_id = $lead->client_id;

        $contact->save();

        Session()->flash('flash_message', 'Lead successfully converted!');
        return view('leads.show');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param StoreLeadRequest|Request $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreLeadRequest $request)
    {
        $getInsertedId = $this->leads->create($request);
        Session()->flash('flash_message', 'Lead is created');

        return redirect()->route('leads.show', $getInsertedId);
    }

   public function show($id)
    {
        return view('leads.show')
            ->withLead($this->leads->find($id))
            ->withUsers($this->users->getAllUsersWithDepartments())
            ->withCompanyname($this->settings->getCompanyName());
    }
```

Route:

```
        Route::get('/data', 'LeadsController@anyData')->name('leads.data');
        Route::get('/create', 'LeadsController@create')->name('leads.create');
        Route::get('/show/{id}', 'LeadsController@show')->name('leads.show');
        Route::get('convertLeads/{id}', 'LeadsController@convertLeads')->name('leads.convertLeads');
        Route::get('/my', 'LeadsController@my')->name('leads.my');
        Route::get('/mydata', 'LeadsController@myData')->name('leads.mydata');
        Route::patch('/updateassign/{id}', 'LeadsController@updateAssign');
        Route::patch('/updatestatus/{id}', 'LeadsController@updateStatus');
        Route::patch('/updatefollowup/{id}', 'LeadsController@updateFollowup')->name('leads.followup');
    });
    Route::resource('leads', 'LeadsController');
    Route::post('/comments/{type}/{id}', 'CommentController@store');
```

Views:

```
          <div>
              <table width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      {!!Form::open(array('route' => array('leads.convertLeads', $lead->id)))!!}
                    <td><li>Convert to Contact</li></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><li>Convert to Company</li></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><label for="chkOpportunity">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chkOpportunity" />
                        Convert to Opportunity
                        </label>

                    <div id="dvOpportunity" style="display: none">

                        {!! Form::label('name', __('Lead Name'), ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                          <div class="form-group" style="padding:5px">
                          {!! Form::label('country', __('Value'), ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                          {!! Form::text('company_country', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group" style="padding:5px">
                          {!! Form::label('country', __('Type'), ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                          {!! Form::text('company_country', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group" style="padding:5px">
                          {!! Form::label('country', __('Stage'), ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                          {!! Form::text('company_country', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                          {!! Form::close() !!}
                          </div>
                     </div>
                    </td>


                  </tr>
              </table> 


          <div class="modal-footer" style="margin:-13px; margin-top:4px;">

          <div align="right">
          {!! Form::submit(__('Convert Lead'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

I am not sure which part of these are wrong, I think it is the form? When I click the Convert Lead button (to submit) nothing happens. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have any relationship between this three table ??

Comment: @Gabrielle they are all connected to the Lead table only

Comment: Lead table id will belongs in these three table or not ?

Comment: yes, all of these three tables have lead_id in them

Comment: In `convertLeads($id)` what you've done ??

Comment: It is to copy some data from the Lead table into Company and Contact table. But it doesn't work, when I clicked the submit button, nothing happens. Also, I want to insert some data into the Opportunity table too, but still trying to figure out how to.

Comment: what is "nothing happens"?  note the submit button is outside the form, you can try moving it inside the form

Comment: by nothing happens, i mean the button doesnt work, no changes, nothing. Oh, I have tried moving the button inside the form, still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

try to place the form above the table tag

like this

```
 <div>{!!Form::open(array('route' => array('leads.convertLeads', $lead->id)))!!}
          <table width="100%">
              <tr>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><li>Convert to Contact</li></td>
```

Comment: thank you, this one made the button worked! but there are still multiple errors that i encounter. One of them is: ```(3/3) QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry``` 

I will try to Google it first, I think it has something to do with my controller?